# Calculating the probability of something given the hazard rate function?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose that the life distribution of a lightbulb of brand A has hazard rate function $λ_A(t) = t^{3}$
,
t > 0.
 What is the probability that a brand A lightbulb burns out in less than 2 years?

Comment: You need to determine $F$ from the differential equation: $F'(t)+t^3F(t)=t^3$

Comment: Empirically about $0.9817$

Comment: @Stef: I'm not sure I grok the form of your differential equation.  It seems to me it should be the much simpler $f'(t) = -t^3f(t)$, with $f(0) = 1$.  If one determines $f(t)$, then the answer to the question is just $1-f(2)$, which (if evaluated) yields a quantity close to Henry's empirical value.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, you are very right. You observed that you can write $f(t)$ not only as $F'(t)$ but as well as $-(1-F(t))'$. This simplifies things a lot. You can write it as an answer, or if you do not want, then I can write it.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $$λ_A(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$$ Observe that this can be equivalently written as $$λ_A(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}=-\frac{\left(1-F(t)\right)'}{1-F(t)}=\left[-\ln\left(1-F(t)\right)\right]'$$ Thus you need to solve the equation $$t^3=\left[-\ln\left(1-F(t)\right)\right]' \iff \frac{t^4}{4}+c=-\ln\left(1-F(t)\right)$$ Since $F(0)=0$ (the bulb cannot have negative lifetime) then $c=0$ and therefore the above equation can be written as $$\frac{t^4}{4}=-\ln\left(1-F(t)\right) \implies e^{-\frac{t^4}{4}}=1-F(t)$$ which implies that $$F(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t^4}{4}}$$ You need to solve for $t=2$ i.e. $$F(2)=1-e^{-\frac{2^4}{4}}=1-0.018316=0.981684$$

---

The key observation to solve for $F(t)$ was to observe that not only $f(t)=F'(t)$ (as is well known) but also $$f(t)=-(1-F(t))'$$